# Why are my attempts to update anwsers rejected

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I tried to edit an answer after a ticket linked there was resolved:
Rejected: "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

I tried to edit another answer, after a change (promised there) was implemented in next version.
Rejected: "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

This reason is totally uninformative, especially given that one of goals of edits is supposedly:

> To include additional information only found in comments, so all of
>   the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

So what, am I supposed to comment on it, and then incorporate my comment with an edit?
All my attempts at updating questions (except for correcting broken links) are rejected like this, it's totally de-motivating.

Another reason for editing the post, that the help page gives is:

> To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**

The way I see it updating the answer about ticket status is exactly this.
Add information about recently released version also seems to fit here.

Comment: Give an example of the edit you tried to make

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4125012) the one?

Comment: Or is it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1545241) one or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/497834)?

Comment: Mostly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4125012) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1545241)

Comment: no, you are not supposed to comment, wait, then edit it in. Just comment and be done. Sometimes authors who don't understand editing will reply to a comment saying "yes, that's right, good point." After that happens, and some time passes without the author incorporating the comment into the question, it's appropriate to suggest an edit to take care of that. But don't use comment-wait-edit as a slower version of suggest-a-material-change.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged, while the exact format of you edit could be slightly improved, your edits are still far better than 90% of the ones I get to see on SO.

Comment: Your edit suggestions seem fine to me.

Comment: @Leeor thanks, but SO is too usefult to me to get discouraged that easily. However I'm seriously concerned about impact of this on new users - the justifications are very opaque and it doesn't encourage participation;, just like it was with question closing (I still think it's not far from ideal, but it got better)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4125012: updating this answer to mention the outcome of the bug report is exactly the kind of things we hope to see in edits. However, please update the post so that it reads seamlessly. Don't add “EDIT: blah”; make the answer reflect the current status.

Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1545241: updating this answer as new versions of the software have come out is exactly the kind of things we hope to see in edits. In fact, the original answer was not very good: “the next release” is obviously a phrasing that's going to age very fast. Mentioning specific version numbers is a lot more useful. The sentence you added about “the current version” suffers from the same defect.

In summary, **these two edits should not have been rejected**.

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow (alone, as far as I know, among the Stack Exchange sites) suffers from reviewers who reject attempts at improving the quality of the site, in flagrant contradiction with the [**rules on editing**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) which you correctly read. I'm sorry you ran into them.

Comment: @flagrant contradiction - I think that the rules are ambiguous enough to allow quite divergent interpretations. I believe the help page on editing should be revised. I know Servy already suggested above that I should propose changes myself, but I don't really feel like I have enough experience with editing to propose policy revisions. I just know they are unclear now.

Answer (score 2):

You should not add **your own material** to an answer using the suggested edit mechanism. Such edits should always be rejected. If you want that material added, leave a comment on the answer.

Sometimes there are already comments on the answer, either from the author of the answer or agreed to by that author, and you feel (correctly) you would be doing the site a service by bringing them into the body of the post. (A side note, please don't use the style of adding **EDIT:** at the bottom, just incorporate the information where it belongs.) If your edits need to be reviewed it is **vital** that you provide an accurate edit summary. One like `A notice about Scanner not throwing exceptions from underlying Readable` says **what** you did, but not **why**. Reviewers cannot see the comments on the post, so if you are incorporating material from comments, **say so**. Something like `author agreed in comments that this can hide exceptions, bringing into body of answer` will usually lead to the edit being accepted.

Also consider the possibility that what you should be doing is writing a new answer. You have this new information, a ticket has been resolved, and it's possible that the best thing to do is compose your own answer that includes your extra information. Adding a line or two to an existing answer may not give that new information the attention it deserves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however (with all due respect) why should I take your word for it? Why isn't this information to be found on the editing help page.

Comment: Or to put it more simply: there was an overhaul of canned reasons for closing a question recently, I think the canned edit reject responses need the same.

Comment: @JakubBochenski what is unclear about `This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.` ? You were trying to reply to or comment on the post, to add material to it. All I've done is translate that terse message for you into something longer with examples. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing is clear that you are not to change the meaning of a post with a suggested edit.

Comment: Firstly: why the "or"? Can't we have two canned responses? Secondly: rejecting an edit because it's "incorrect" doesn't explain anything. Thirdly: the help page says: "Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so.". I don't find anything there that would support your assertion that I should not add new material to the anwser

Comment: Another reason for edits given in help is "add updates as the post ages". How is that not adding new material?

Comment: @JakubBochenski Of the two edits you linked, the first does fall under that, or at least the first half of the edit does.  The second edit is just adding entirely new information, and is not updating the information in the answer due to changes over time.  It's just some separate information that you think might be useful additional information.  That's *exactly* what comments are there for.  The same is true of the second half of your first edit.  It belongs as a comment.

Comment: @Servy your right in pointing out that some of the information there could be put into comments; however in light of this I find the point about "including information only found in comments" rather confusing; while I think I understand where the line is drawn now the help page does a terrible job at explaining it

Comment: @JakubBochenski Edits are just inherently complex to begin with, hence the difficulty in explaining them.  If you have ideas for improved wording, by all means suggest them.

Comment: @Servy it's always easier to complain than create :) How about stating the "only include material from comments that the orginial author acknowledged" rule in a more explicit way? How do you suggest changes to the help page? Contact Support | Other?

Comment: @JakubBochenski A meta post about it is fine.

Comment: @Servy meta post = meta question?

Comment: @JakubBochenski Yes.  I say post simply because on meta a question isn't necessarily a question.  It can be a proposal, suggestion, discussion, bug report, etc.

Comment: Nonsense. This was a textbook case of “adding updates as the post ages”. Apart from the “EDIT:” bit, these edits should have been accepted.